# CGContextFillPath don't fill in intersect sub path

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-core

I have a weird problem when using `QuartzCore` to draw on a view using user's touch. My idea is draw ellipse in `touchesBegan` and draw some subpath in `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnd`. My code here:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineJoin (context, kCGLineJoinRound);
    CGContextSetLineCap (context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    //CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (path == nil) {
        CGPathRelease(path);
        path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    }
    strokeWidth = 10;
    CGFloat halfWidth = strokeWidth / 2;
    CGPoint p = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(p.x - halfWidth, p.y - halfWidth, strokeWidth, strokeWidth));

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

static CGPoint prevLeft, prevRight;
CGPoint midPoint(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2) {
    return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x) / 2, (p1.y + p2.y) / 2);
}

CGPoint triPoint(CGPoint p1, CGPoint p2, CGPoint p3) {
    return CGPointMake((p1.x + p2.x + p3.x) / 3, (p1.y + p2.y + p3.y) / 3);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGFloat halfWidth = strokeWidth / 2;
    CGPoint p1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    CGPoint p2 = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint lineVector = CGPointMake(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
    CGFloat len = hypotf(lineVector.x, lineVector.y);
    CGPoint normalVector = CGPointMake(- lineVector.y / len, lineVector.x / len);

    CGFloat valx = normalVector.x * halfWidth;
    CGFloat valy = normalVector.y * halfWidth;

    CGPoint left1 = CGPointMake(p1.x + valx, p1.y + valy);
    CGPoint right1 = CGPointMake(p1.x - valx, p1.y - valy);

    CGPoint left = CGPointMake(p2.x + valx, p2.y + valy);
    CGPoint right = CGPointMake(p2.x - valx, p2.y - valy);

    prevLeft = midPoint(left1, left);
    prevRight = midPoint(right1, right);

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, left1.x , left1.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, left.x, left.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, right.x, right.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, right1.x, right1.y);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGFloat halfWidth = strokeWidth / 2;
    CGPoint p1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    CGPoint p2 = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint lineVector = CGPointMake(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
    CGFloat len = hypotf(lineVector.x, lineVector.y);
    CGPoint normalVector = CGPointMake(- lineVector.y / len, lineVector.x / len);

    CGFloat valx = normalVector.x * halfWidth;
    CGFloat valy = normalVector.y * halfWidth;

    CGPoint left1 = CGPointMake(p1.x + valx, p1.y + valy);
    CGPoint right1 = CGPointMake(p1.x - valx, p1.y - valy);

    CGPoint left = CGPointMake(p2.x + valx, p2.y + valy);
    CGPoint right = CGPointMake(p2.x - valx, p2.y - valy);

    prevLeft = midPoint(left1, left);
    prevRight = midPoint(right1, right);

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, left1.x , left1.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, left.x, left.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, right.x, right.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, right1.x, right1.y);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

But the result when drawing touchesBegan and touchesMoved is here:

[image]

it look likes the intersect between ellipse and subpath is not fill with the selected color. Does anyone have this problem before? I am appreciated with your help.

Thanks,

Comment: The easiest would be to draw the circle as a separate path.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to draw on one path only to use for purpose. Any recommendations?

Comment: Why? What are you actually trying to do? I guess you could draw a half-circle instead, to avoid the overlap...

Comment: I have tried half-circle, it still overlap :-(. I think there is a root problem here, we shouldn't solve it using trick.

Comment: Thing is, the fact that some overlapping regions aren't filled is by design, otherwise you couldn't construct a path that has holes in it (e.g. a donut shape). You have two options for the rule that determines which parts are filled ("even-odd" and "non-zero winding number"), but I don't think changing it would help you in this case.

Comment: I also don't quite understand why you construct the individual line segments by hand instead of just stroking a path with a thick stroke width and using round line caps.

Comment: Because I would like to change the width of stroke based on user's drawing speed. So I must do that myself, using normal vector. Can you show me information about fill mode you mention in previous post? Thanks.

Comment: Hi omz, your suggestion solve my problem. My problem is drawing by clockwise direction. Drawing by counter-clockwise direction will solve this problem.